# Fatal error: Call to a member function addCrumb() on boolean

Tags: magento-2.1, frontend

I have created a module with admin grid i want to show data on frontend with breadcrumb. but i am getting error ..

> Fatal error: Call to a member function addCrumb() on boolean in D:\xampp5.6\htdocs\Magento2.1.0\app\code\Tenx\Faq\Controller\Index\Index.php on line 26

**Tenx\Faq\Controller\Index\Index.php**

```
<?php
namespace Tenx\Faq\Controller\Index;
use Tenx\Faq\Controller\Faq;

class Index extends Faq
{
    public function execute()
    {
            echo "Sarvesh";

        $resPage = $this->_pageFactory->create();
        // Add title which is got by the configuration via backend
        $resPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->set(
            $this->_dataHelper->getHeadTitle()
        );
        // Add breadcrumb
        /** @var \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Breadcrumbs */
        $breadcrumbs = $resPage->getLayout()->getBlock('breadcrumbs');
        $breadcrumbs->addCrumb('home',
            [
                'label' => __('Home'),
                'title' => __('Home'),
                'link' => $this->_url->getUrl('')
            ]
        );
        $breadcrumbs->addCrumb('faq',
            [
                'label' => __('Faq'),
                'title' => __('Faq')
            ]
        );
        return $resPage;
    }
}
```